# How does ASP .NET MVC Application determine which config file to use when it has multiple environments?

Tags: .net, environment-variables, config

I have a .NET 4 application with three different `web.config` files:
`web.dev.config`, `web.test.config`, `web.prod.config`.

I know how to use the file transformation in the application (xdt:Transform) but my question is on the actual servers. What is the configuration I must make on the physical servers not in the app?

For instance, on the test server, should I set the environment variable to test so that when I deploy, the application will know that it is a test server? Is there any configuration on the test IIS web server?

OR simply - I have three physical servers which I want to make dev, test and prod so that I will deploy my .NET APP. Any configurations on the actual physical servers?

Comment: How do you deploy your app? For us, we don't need to maintain different transforms for different environments. Instead, the config file contains placeholder values. When we deploy an app to an environment, our deployment tool (we use Octopus Deploy, but we've also done the same with Azure DevOps) will replace the placeholders with the appropriate settings (connection strings, URLs etc) for that environment. That means you don't have to modify source code to deploy to a new environment. Just inject different values. You can also use the config transform to add the placeholders.

Comment: The approach I just mentioned also has the advantage of keeping potentially sensitive values (like API keys or connection strings) from being in your source code that you check in, since the sensitive info would only be inserted at deploy time via your deployment tool.

Comment: I use Azure DevOps CI/CD for deployment. My question is how does .NET knows which config file to use (web.test.config) when deployed to a test environment for instance? somehow it has to know the physical server is a test server so that it uses the test config file right?

Comment: That's the problem, it *doesn't* know! When you compile the app, you compile with one of the available configurations. At that time, config transforms are applied. So that's why it's not a good idea to use different config transforms for different environments - rebuilding the app to deploy to a new environment is silly. Instead, as part of your CI/CD pipeline, you should compile the application a single time, and then deploy the same artifacts to various environments, customizing the config file *at deployment time* as I described in my previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question

Since I was using azure DevOps for CI/CD, I found the configuration under the pipeline.

Go to the pipeline in question, create a powershell task and in the inline script, you may write a switch statement (powershell script) based on a branch.

```
Param([string]$branchName)
switch -wildcard ($branchName) 
{
   "*/master" {Set-Variable -Name "br" -Value "Production"; break }
   "*/release/*" {Set-Variable -Name "br" -Value "Staging"; break }
   ... here you can continue adding your own branches and which 
   configuration to trigger. }
```

In My case I wanted to add a test server and I wanted my web.test.config file to be used when deployed to a test server. so I added

```
"*/test/*" {Set-Variable -Name "br" -Value "Test"; break }
```

in the above switch statement